# How do I remove the extra space in the artbroad in Photoshop when slicing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I tried to save a gif or image, there are always some extra space in the final result. Does anyone know how to remove the extra space? I have tried to use the slice tool to resize it or crop it but nothing works. I would appreciate a lot if you can help. Thanks!

[image: When I save to web/ save as JPEG file, you can see the extra space]

[image: Cannot see it in photoshop before save]

Answer (score 1):

When exporting slices via `File` > `Export` > `Save For Web (Legacy)`, make sure you select the slice by clicking on it, then when the Save Optimised dialog pops up, set the `Slices option` to `Selected Slices`.

[image: Screenshot]
Obviously, this screenshot is from Windows, but there should be a similar option in the Mac version.